# Cannot install package: "undefined reference to dtrsm_"

Tags: r

I am trying to install a private R package on a 64-bit Windows 10 machine. The documentation tells me to install R-3.2.5, TDM-GCC-64 and put it in the path. Then try to install the package. I have binary and source file for the package.

When I try to load from source, I get

```
chol2.o:chol2.cpp:(.text+0x8d2): undefined reference to `dtrsm_'
chol2.o:chol2.cpp:(.text+0xab2): undefined reference to `dsyrk_'
computeOtherCov.o:computeOtherCov.cpp:(.text+0x91c): undefined reference to `dtrmm_'
computeOtherCov.o:computeOtherCov.cpp:(.text+0x9c8): undefined reference to `dsyrk_'
computeOtherCov.o:computeOtherCov.cpp:(.text+0xc89): undefined reference to `dtrmv_'
symv.o:symv.cpp:(.text+0x71c): undefined reference to `dsymv_'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
no DLL was created
```

When I try to install from binary file, I get

```
library(LIV)
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
  unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/a619031/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/LIV/libs/x64/LIV.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘LIV’
```

The package depends on Rcpp and by googling it seems like the issue is about linking to BLAS library but I can't tell why it is not working exactly and don't know how to fix it.

Any ideas on a possible cause or/and a fix?